# How can I know if a pattern corresponds to a string pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, undocumented

What would be the best way to detect if a pattern corresponds to a string pattern ?
An invalid string pattern `p` would lead to an error in `StringMatchQ[string, p]` for example.

Comment: Have a look at `System\`Dump\`validStringExpressionQ[]`.

Comment: Yes that's the kind of built-in function I was looking for thanks. Maybe you could put the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At Faysal's behest: there's the (undocumented) function `` System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[] ``:

```
System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ["**"]
   True

System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[_ ~~ 1]
   False
```

Comment: A look at `??System\`Dump\`validStringExpressionQ` is particularly enlightening...

Comment: Indeed so basically the pattern is passed to StringMatchQ in the general case and the function checks that no error occured.

Comment: +1. A look at the implementation reveals some unpleasant behavior,e.g. ``stpatt = "**"; System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[stpatt]`` returns `False`, while ``System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[Evaluate[stpatt]]`` returns `True`. I would prefer to get `True` in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

```
StringPatternQ[_String | _StringExpression | _RegularExpression] = True;
StringPatternQ[_] = False;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is the internal `` GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ ``:

```
? GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ
```

> `StringPatternQ[expr] gives True if expr is a valid string pattern,`
>      `suitable for use with e.g. StringMatchQ`

It is a predicate that allows for the most inclusive match, thus it returns `True` for any pattern that *could* stand for a string pattern.

```
 GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ[_]   (* ==> True *)
```

However, it is less precise as `` System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ ``:

```
patt = {"s", "*", "**", __, Except@_, x, _ ~~ 1};
GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ /@ patt
System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ /@ patt
Quiet@Check[StringMatchQ["s", #], $Failed] & /@ patt
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True, False, False}
> {True, True, True, True, False, False, False}
> {True, True, True, True, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed}
> ```

Leonid's example:

```
stpatt = "**";
System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[stpatt]           (* ==> False *)
System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[Evaluate[stpatt]] (* ==> True *)
GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ[stpatt]              (* ==> True *)
GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ[Evaluate[stpatt]]    (* ==> True *)
```

According to its `PrintDefinitions`, it recognizes the following arguments as string patterns:

```
spq[e_Alternatives] := AllTrue[e, spq];
spq[e_List] := AllTrue[e, spq];
spq[_String] := True;
spq[DatePattern[e_List]] := Developer`StringVectorQ[e];
spq[DatePattern[e_List, sep_]] := Developer`StringVectorQ[e] && spq[sep];
spq[Verbatim[Longest][e_]] := spq[e];
spq[Verbatim[Shortest][e_]] := spq[e];
spq[Verbatim[Repeated][e_, ___]] := spq[e];
spq[Verbatim[RepeatedNull][e_]] := spq[e];
spq[Verbatim[Except][e_]] := spq[e];
spq[Verbatim[Except][e_, f_]] := spq[e] && spq[f];
spq[Verbatim[Pattern][_, patt_]] := spq[patt];
spq[Verbatim[Verbatim][_String]] := True;
spq[Verbatim[Condition][patt_, _]] := spq[patt];
spq[Verbatim[PatternTest][patt_, _]] := spq[patt];
spq[e_AnyOrder] := AllTrue[e, spq];
spq[e_FixedOrder] := AllTrue[e, spq];
spq[expr_] := MatchQ[expr, $AtomicPatterns];
```

Comment: The `$AtomicPatterns` is ``GeneralUtilities`Strings`PackagePrivate`$AtomicPatterns``.

Answer (score 0):

### `` System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ ``

This function calls `StringMatchQ`. Only if `StringMatchQ` works normally, it returns `True`.

Its definition is quite simple:

```
System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ[a_HoldPattern] :=
  Quiet@Head@StringMatchQ["", StringExpression@a] =!= StringMatchQ
```

### `` StringPattern`StringPatternQ ``

This one has a quite complex implementation, and is possibly **the** function **called by** `StringMatchQ`.

### `` GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ ``

`` GeneralUtilities` `` is a convenient package. The function here has a complex implementation (more complex than the next one), but is not quite reliable.

Unexpected behavior can be produced by:

- `StringPatternQ@String[]`
- `StringPatternQ@Except@""`
- `StringPatternQ@Condition[anything, anything]`
- `StringPatternQ@PatternTest[anything, anything]`

### `` System`ConvertersDump`StringPatternQ `` and `` FileFormatDump`StringPatternQ ``

Currently, these two functions have the same implementation (which is quite simple and less reliable):

```
System`ConvertersDump`StringPatternQ[x_] := MatchQ[x,
  Alternatives[_String, _StringExpression, _RegularExpression, _Alternatives]
]
```